# Arraylist issue when adding new member "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I am trying to create an arraylist of class objects.  When I go to add a class object to the array list I get the "non-static variable....static context" error.

My arraylist:

```
ArrayList<CookieClass> cookieList = new ArrayList<CookieClass> ();
cookieList.add(new CookieClass("chocolate chip", 20));
```

My class:

```
class CookieClass
{
     private String cookieName;
     private int cookieNum;

     public CookieClass(String cookie, int num)
     {
         cookieName = cookie;
         cookieNum = num;
     }

}
```

Comment: are you getting exception/strackTrace or is this IDE warning ?

Comment: You should be getting an error earlier on: Your `CookieClass` won't compile, the `;` in `public CookieClass(String cookie, int num);` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that but the extra semi colon was just a copy / paste issue as I was formatting the code for the post.  The semi colon isn't in the actual code and I've adjusted the OP to reflect that.

Comment: Also, this is an exception / StackTrace.

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CookieClass {

    private String cookieName;
    private int cookieNum;

    public CookieClass(String cookie, int num) {
        cookieName = cookie;
        cookieNum = num;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CookieClass{" +
                "cookieName='" + cookieName + '\'' +
                ", cookieNum=" + cookieNum +
                '}';
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        List<CookieClass> cookieList = new ArrayList<CookieClass>();
        cookieList.add(new CookieClass("chocolate chip", 20));
        cookieList.add(new CookieClass("Strawberry chip", 30));

        for(CookieClass c: cookieList){
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
CookieClass{cookieName='chocolate chip', cookieNum=20}
CookieClass{cookieName='Strawberry chip', cookieNum=30}
```

Comment: Still having the same issue.

Comment: Can you print your stack trace? -- this runs fine on my system. what is the exact error your are getting?

Comment: Its because u made your variables private

Comment: are you trying to "use" this class somewhere? (not in this class?) can you show me other class?   -- remember main method is static

Comment: I figured it out.  The closing curly bracket for my public class was enclosing my cookieclass.  Once I adjusted the bracket it worked without issue.  Thanks for the help

Comment: did my answer help you? not sure why I got -1